# SHIBBOLETH SP - Shibboleth handler invoked at an unconfigured location - Shibboleth.sso/Session/

Tags: security

On Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I am trying to get shibboleth configured.  When I go to `https://mysite/secure/index.php`, it works properly, I can authenticate, etc. but when I go to `https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Status` (or any other `https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/*`) I get the following message:

> shibsp::ConfigurationException
>
> The system encountered an error at Mon Jul 10 12:06:32 2017
>
> To report this problem, please contact the site administrator at root@localhost.
>
> Please include the following message in any email:
>
> shibsp::ConfigurationException at (`https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Session/`)
>
> Shibboleth handler invoked at an unconfigured location.

My shibboleth2.xml is as follows (comments removed for brevity):

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" clockSkew="1800">
 <ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://mysite/shibboleth" REMOTE_USER="eppn">
     <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false" relayState="ss:mem" handlerSSL="true" cookieProps="https">
         <SSO entityID="https://idp.testshib.org/idp/shibboleth">
             SAML2 SAML1
         </SSO>
         <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>
         <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false"/>
         <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1 ::1"/>
         <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="true"/>
         <Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed"/>
     </Sessions>
     <Errors supportContact="root@localhost" logoLocation="/shibboleth-sp/logo.jpg" styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>
     <MetadataProvider type="XML" uri="http://www.testshib.org/metadata/testshib-providers.xml" backingFilePath="testshib-two-idp-metadata.xml" reloadInterval="180000" />
     <AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-map.xml"/>
     <AttributeResolver type="Query" subjectMatch="true"/>
     <AttributeFilter type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-policy.xml"/>
     <CredentialResolver type="File" key="my_key" certificate="my_cert" extractNames="false"/>
 </ApplicationDefaults>
 <SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="security-policy.xml"/>
 <ProtocolProvider type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="protocols.xml"/>
</SPConfig>
```

I have examined every config file I can find, every setting I can think of.
I turned on debug mode for native.logger and shibd.logger but not found anything.

What is wrong? or where should I look?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not clearly about Unix and/or Linux. What OS is the system running? This question might be more appropriately posted at [SU].

Comment: Sorry, i didn't specify Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Also check out https://serverfault.com. This looks like a piece of software for corporate use, which means folks at Super User are likely to redirect you to ServerFault anyway.

Comment: Found the answer:

The problem was actually with the way Apache is configured.  It was rewriting urls to add a / at the end of each url.  so `https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Session` became `https://mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Session/`.  It is always the minor things!

Since the Apache configuration is necessary for another portion of the project, I changed the <Handler> Location attribute to add a slash at the end and it worked perfectly!  HT- Scott Cantor on Users@shibboleth.net mailing list!